# Docker : Dynamically created file copy to local machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker, I'm dynamically creating a file which is in docker container and want to copy that local machine at the same time, please let me know how it is possible through volumes.

For now, I have to use the below command again and again to check the file data :

```
docker cp source destination
```

How it can be done through volumes, the file format will be in .csv or .xlsx? I mean what should I write the command in docker files so that it can copy the file

Answer (score 1):

What you need is volume. You have to add your current directory as a volume to the docker container when you first create the container so that they are the same folder. By doing this, you'll be able to sync the files in that folder automatically. But I'm assuming you're using docker for development environment.

This is how I run my container.

`docker run -d -it --name {container_name} --volume $PWD:{directory_in_container} --entrypoint /bin/bash {image_name}`

In addition to your run command, you have to add `--volume $PWD:{directory_in_container}` to your run script.

If you have a problem again, just add more detail to your question.
Things you can add might be your Dockerfile, and how you first run your container.